# data structures for dynamic large sparse matrix in C

Tags: c, data-structures, sparse-matrix

what's the best suitable data structure to use in C for sparse dynamic matrix.
I know about the Yale format but it's for static matrices.
I need to be able to add rows column and values in it.

Comment: Just FYI, Any question starting with "What is the best...." asked on SO has not so much a condition of "if" it will be closed, as *when* it will be closed.

Comment: You can only define the best data structure given an approximation of the matrix size, and the operations you want to optimize. A sparse 100x100 matrix which need to be transposed? slap an array and be done with it.

Answer (score 3):

In general, an array of linked lists. If most of the operations are row-based, each list represent a row, otherwise, each list represent a column. You can [get more info here](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ab/15-123S09/lectures/Lecture%2011%20%20-%20%20Array%20of%20Linked%20Lists.pdf)

```
 typedef struct matrix { 
    node**  rowList;     // rowList is a pointer to the array of rows 
    node** columnList; // column list is a pointer to the array of columns. 
    int  rows, columns;  // store the number of rows and columns of the matrix 
 } matrix


 typedef struct node { 
    int row, column, 
    double value; 
    struct node*  rowPtr; 
    struct node*  colPtr; 
 } node;
```

Answer (score 0):

A hashtable.

Example: Key could be  `row<<16|col`.

Comment: This is good for random-access (if you want to set/clear at locations). If you want to iterate through rows/cols then use UmNyobe's answer instead.

Comment: Of course not only good for `set/clear` at locations but also for `get` at specific locations.